# Zend_Form error messages

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-form-element

I have a custom markup for my zend_form and i try to set a css class (**class="hasErrors"**) to my input field. My rendered form elements look like this:

```
<div id="teamname-element" class="formRow">
    <input type="text" name="teamname" id="teamname" value="" placeholder="Teamname">
</div>
```

with errors it looks like this:

```
<div id="teamname-element" class="formRow">
    <input type="text" name="teamname" id="teamname" value="" placeholder="Teamname">
    <ul class="errors">
        <li>Your teamname is to short!</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

is it possible to set a css class to the input field without using javascript?

```
<input class="hasErrors" type="text" name="teamname" id="teamname" value="" placeholder="Teamname">
```

A form element is created like this:

```
$this->addElement(new Nut_Form_Element_Text('teamname', array(
    'Label'      => 'Teamname',
    'validators' => array( array('StringLength', FALSE, array(1, 25)), $TeamRegex),
    'filters'    => array('StringTrim', 'StripTags'),
)));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here we create a form class that extends Zend_Form. We override the isValid() method. We loop through the form->elements and add a class of “error” if the hasErrors() method returns true. We also do a check to see if a class attribute already exists using the getAttrib() method and if so we append the “error” class using a space to separate.

```
class MyForm extends Zend_Form
{
    public function isValid($data)
    {
        $valid = parent::isValid($data);

        foreach ($this->getElements() as $element) {
            if ($element->hasErrors()) {
                $oldClass = $element->getAttrib('class');
                if (!empty($oldClass)) {
                    $element->setAttrib('class', $oldClass . ' hasError');
                } else {
                    $element->setAttrib('class', 'hasError');
                }
            }
        }

        return $valid;
    }
}
```

Now, when you call the isValid method, it will automatically add a class of error to any fields that do not pass validation.